# Raspberry Pi 4/BCM2711 Peripheral Base Address differs in documentation from hardware

Tags: raspberry-pi, arm

In the bcm2711-peripherals.pdf, it states on page 6:

> When running in 32-bit mode, the ARM uses LPAE mode to enable it to access the full 32GB address space.
> Physical  addresses  range  from  0x4_7C00_0000  to  0x4_7FFF_FFFF  for  Main  peripherals,  and  from  0x4_C000_0000  to
> 0x4_FFFF_FFFF for ARM Local peripherals.

I understand that the address of 0x4_7C00_0000 (ie main peripheral base address) would be translated to 0x0_FC00_0000 when translating to low peripheral mode, but everywhere I read has the peripheral base address as 0x0_FE00_0000. Why is the 0x0_FE00_0000 value correct instead of 0x0_FC00_0000?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The address range `0xfc00_0000 - 0xffff_ffff` (in low peripheral mode) is indeed reserved for peripherals.  But it just so happens that the "interesting" ones (timers, serial, GPIO, DMA) are located between `0xfe00_0000 - 0xfeff_ffff`.  For each of the various peripherals, the manual specifies the addresses where its I/O registers are located, and skimming the manual, they all seem to be in the `0xfe*` range.

Thus `0xfe00_0000` is effectively the base address for the peripherals that are relevant to "bit banging" type applications, which is what Raspberry Pi programmers often are most interested in.

I am not sure what, if anything, is located between `0xfc00_0000 - 0xfdff_ffff`.  It could be registers for some of the Pi's other I/O hardware (ethernet, USB, video, etc) or it could simply be reserved address space that is not used by this chip.